Using SQL query to remove non matching duplicates in two columns
Can anybody help me with a query that can be executed to only show one card_number entry per day no matter the time in the transit_date. See image below. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

The image is as far as I can get. I then tried removing the duplicates in excel but was unsuccessful. There are over 300K rows on average for each month the report needs to be generated. I effectively need only one card number to show per day and not multiple entries. We are just trying to see who badged in on any given day in a months period.

Try adding ... GROUP BY CARD_NUMBER

Please don’t link to images. Add all relevant information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted

Thanks both for the info. I have tried group by card with no success.

This question is similar to: Get top 1 row of each group. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi @siggemannen the question has been answered by me, sadly RM didn't just didn't tick the answer.

We don't post images of code or data here. No one is going to look at that query or sample data as it is, meaning you won't get help until you edit the question to post the data in a more usable way.

Thanks all for the assist. This is the first time I have posted a question. I have taken all suggestions onboard for the next time and ticked the answer, which i was not aware of either. Thats what I get for not reading the instructions correctly. Have a wonderful day all.

I have come across something like this in the past, This code might help.
WITH RankedEntries AS (
    SELECT
        CARD_NUMBER,
        TRANSIT_DATE,
        NAME,
        SURNAME,
        IDENTIFIER,
        USERTYPE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CARD_NUMBER, CAST(TRANSIT_DATE AS DATE) 
            ORDER BY TRANSIT_DATE
        ) AS rn
    FROM
        your_table_name
    WHERE
        TRANSIT_DATE >= '2024-01-01' -- Replace with your start date
        AND TRANSIT_DATE < '2024-02-01' -- Replace with your end date
)
SELECT
    CARD_NUMBER,
    CAST(TRANSIT_DATE AS DATE) AS TRANSIT_DAY,
    NAME,
    SURNAME,
    IDENTIFIER,
    USERTYPE
FROM
    RankedEntries
WHERE
    rn = 1
ORDER BY
    CARD_NUMBER,
    TRANSIT_DAY;


Thanks for the info. I ran the code but it gives me the following:

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 9
'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 18
'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Completion time: 2024-08-08T12:52:27.0816821+01:00

@RM you need to put the date you want there

Hi Derek, apologies I did not give more context. I changed the date to the dates I needed as per your comments in the script. It does not seem to like having the DATE function before the transit_date. It only runs without that function being added. It gives me similar results to what I have in my image. If I could get it to a place where it only shows one card per day that would finish it off.

@RM no worries, I have changed the code, I just cast the date let's see what happens.

Derek, this is absolutely perfect. Thanks very much for your swift assistance. Have a great rest of the day.

Try with distinct as date is not in the select statement
e.g.
SELECT distinct
  c.[CARD_NUMBER],
  c.[NAME],
  c.[SURNAME],
  c.[IDENTIFIER],
  c.[USERTYPE]
FROM
  [dbo].[card_calling] c;


